# Kotlin Foo::class.java "Unresolved Reference: Java" error

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to convert my Java code of `HomePage.class` to Kotlin. I am following the instructions on [Kotlin.org](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html):

> **getClass()**
>
> To retrieve the type information from an object, we use the javaClass
>   extension property.
>
> `val fooClass = foo.javaClass`
>
> Instead of Java’s `Foo.class` use
>   `Foo::class.java`.
>
> `val fooClass = Foo::class.java`

I have a class called HomePage that extends AppCompatActivity (in Android). I am using Android Studio. I tried doing `HomePage::class.java` and it has an error: `Unresolved reference: java`

[image]

How do I get this to work?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The issue is most likely that you forgot to depend on the [reflection libraries](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html#class-references) which were needed for the reflective functions of Kotlin.

> On the Java platform, the runtime component required for using the
>   reflection features is distributed as a separate JAR file
>   (kotlin-reflect.jar). This is done to reduce the required size of the
>   runtime library for applications that do not use reflection features.
>   If you do use reflection, please make sure that the .jar file is added
>   to the classpath of your project.

[Source](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html)

Answer (score 17):

It turns out, I was using an older version of Kotlin, and it wasn't configured correctly. I edited the gradle file to include the latest beta version, and selected the option that configures Kotlin, and it works now.

In gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.0.0-beta-3594'
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
...

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
}
```

Comment: For me helped not beta, but adding all your dependencies

Answer (score 13):

I Put in the beginning of Gradle (Module app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

and

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
```

or

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
```

in the dependencies section

In the build.gradle (Project)

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.0'
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This happened to me after updating Android Studio and the Kotlin plugin, which required migration to a newer version of Kotlin. After configuring everything correctly, the error still persisted. Deleting `.idea` folder and reloading did not help, but good old `File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart` did the trick for me.

Answer (score 2):

For easy reference, here are the reflection dependencies when using **Gradle**:

**Reflection libraries from the [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html#configuring-dependencies) for Gradle in your `build.gradle`**

```
dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8"
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect"
    testCompile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test"
    testCompile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit"
}
```

**Reflection libraries syntax for Kotlin Script Gradle DSL in your `build.gradle.kts`**

```
dependencies {
    compile(kotlin("stdlib"))
    compile(kotlin("reflect"))
    compile(kotlin("test"))
    compile(kotlin("test-junit"))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In build.gradle (app) I had:

```
  implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0'
```

And I replaced it by

```
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.5.0'
```

And it worked!
The core version also killed some of y functions like: forEach

Comment: Now it is 1.7.0

Answer (score 1):

I used

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
```

Instead of

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
```

Answer (score 1):

i use this

implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"

invalided cache & restart android studio!works fine!!

Comment: Invalidate caches worked, i had a clean project from the AS examples, it should work as it is

Answer (score 0):

I copied the class from other project and forgot to change the class package name.
when I changed, it fixed

Answer (score 0):

I saw this in AndroidStudio with Kotlin 1.2.71 and none of the above fixed it for me.

What <s>sadly</s> hilariously worked for me was closing the project, telling AndroidStudio to forget about the project and re-opening from the folder. Presto, no unresolved reference. Weird, I know.

Comment: How did you tell him that ? Was that with an `Invalidate Cache and restart` ? Or was it with something else ?

Comment: @Elynad no, although I would try `Invalidate Cache and Restart` first. I went to the screen when no project is open and clicked that ecks (x) which tells it to forget the project and then re-opened it anew. Something with the initial setup *shrug*

Answer (score 0):

In my case reducing version of kotlin fixed the issue

Change

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.21'
```

To

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.11'
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in your Module build gradle

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
```

In Project build gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.21'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error when i downloaded and run android studio canary(artic fox). Since then my android studio(normal one) was giving this error i applied all the solutions given above but nothing worked . So i completely uninstalled the android studio and reinstalled the latest one (this was the only option left)

Answer (score 0):

For me it work with just **Invalidate Cache and restart**