# Room database using kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I am converting java code to kotlin code and i am getting type unresolved java class error.

My Java Class is

```
Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(), EventDatabase.class, "event_db").build();
```

Converted Kotlin class

```
 Room.databaseBuilder<EventDatabase>(context.applicationContext, EventDatabase::class.java!!, "event_db").build()
```

Thank you.

Comment: I presume you aren't using latest version of kotlin. Can you confirm the version?

Comment: It could be because of the reflection apis missing in class path. Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34144392/kotlin-fooclass-java-unresolved-reference-java-error

Comment: i am using android studio to convert the java class to kolin class

Comment: Can any one tell me why i am down voting is there wrong question i have asked??

Comment: nothing to do with me! I haven't downvoted..

Comment: You do not even say what the error message is, nor show anything that would help resolve an unresolved class error (i.e. dependencies), nor the stack trace of the error.  For me, that would cause a downvote until you added those to the question.  For example, you know the problem is with gradle, but you never showed your gradle file.

Comment: @JaysonMinard Fist of all thanks for adding comment there,

Comment: @JayaonMinard I am using android studio 3.0 within that i have an existing project developed in java,I am not much more familiar with kotlin but trying to learn kotlin by simply converting my java code to kotlin. In existing project i don't added the gradle dependency for kotlin support that was the causing actual problem thats it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Error is resolved i need first add kotlin dependency in my gradle file.