# Go to next activity in android Kotlin; Unresolved class reference

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to go to next activity with my button listener and it says `unresolved reference java`
Here is my code:

```
btn?.setOnClickListener(object: View.OnClickListener {
      override fun onClick(view: View): Unit {
         val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity,NextActivity::class.java)
            Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity,"helllo",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
         }
      })
```

**NOTE:** Here the `NextActivity` is also a kotlin file.

**Error shown in image**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to either upgrade Kotlin to the lastest version, or add a reference to kotlin-reflect below the stdlib dependency (will look like this):

```
compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version"
```

Comment: Get reference from here but thanks it's working https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34144392/kotlin-fooclass-java-unresolved-reference-java-error

Answer (score 2):

```
btn?.setOnClickListener {
   startActivity(Intent(this, NextActivity::class.java))
}
```

Comment: You can see in my question i am implement the same..

Comment: @SalmanGhumsani no, you did not call startActivity

Comment: Basically, if I am saying, I don't want to `startActivity` only I want the instance of the Intent then?

Answer (score 1):

As the @Hong Duan's comment

Possibly you have to add the kotlin's stdlib depency in your gradle script

```
compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [anko](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko/blob/master/README.md) you can use the following

```
val intent = IntentFor<NextActivity>()
```