# Why we write NextActivity::class.java although this is a kotlin class?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

We have to write this line with the extension .java although its extension is .kt I think Kotlin file converts into the java file but the java also converts in byte code so we can also use .class file If the Kotlin code converts into the java code.

`NextActivity::class.java`  **to** `NextActivity::class.kt //not worked`

```
btn?.setOnClickListener {
   startActivity(Intent(this, NextActivity::class.java))
}
```

So the question is why we write the .java in `NextActivity::class.java`

Question arises from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45354967/go-to-next-activity-in-android-kotlin-unresolved-class-reference).

Comment: `java` is just a **property** to get the class from `KClass`. It is not an extension.

Comment: @holi-java you are right here after analysis I understand that `NextActivity::class` returns `KClass` reference and the `KClass` has the property .java and the `Intent(Context packageContext, Class cls)` param type is `Class` so final answer would be this is not the extension.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because you want to access the methods of the [Java Class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html).

I think they are not reimplemented from scratch in Kotlin so, in order to access them, you have to "reflect" your kotlin class to a Java one.

`NextActivity::class` returns the `KClass` reference and the `KClass` has the [property](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-class/index.html)  `java` and the `Intent` contructor signature is `Intent(Context packageContext, Class cls)` so the second parameter is `Class` type So the final answer would be **this is not the extension this is just property.**

Comment: It means we can write the .kt to .java and it will be detectable right?

Comment: ::class.kt doesn't exist, only ::class exist but it will return a KClass (Kotlin Class) and not a Class (in the sense of Java Class). Probably the NextActivity requires a Class parameter and not a KClass one

Comment: I tried using .kt and it didn't work. And your answer is right Kotlin is still baking and we still need to borrow alot from Java

Answer (score 4):

You are calling Java code from Kotlin. Intent is Java class in Android.

Doc: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html#class-references

> Note that a Kotlin class reference is not the same as a Java class
>   reference. To obtain a Java class reference, use the .java property on
>   a KClass instance.

You cannot pass Kotlin class reference to Java (Intent in your case) and so you have to pass Java class reference.

From the interop doc: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#java-reflection

> Java reflection works on Kotlin classes and vice versa. As mentioned
>   above, you can use instance::class.java, ClassName::class.java or
>   instance.javaClass to enter Java reflection through java.lang.Class.