# Kotlin Android start new Activity

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, android-activity

I want to start another activity on Android but I get this error:

> Please specify constructor invocation; classifier 'Page2' does not have a companion object

after instantiating the `Intent` class. What should I do to correct the error? My code:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }

    fun buTestUpdateText2 (view: View) {
        val changePage = Intent(this, Page2) 
        // Error: "Please specify constructor invocation; 
        // classifier 'Page2' does not have a companion object"

        startActivity(changePage)
    }

}
```

Comment: @BakaWaii that page does not exist anymore.

Comment: Had the same error while converting a java app over to Kotlin. Had to add dependencies. The IDE was actually warning me. But I also found the answers here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34144392/kotlin-fooclass-java-unresolved-reference-java-error

Answer (score 241, accepted):

To start an `Activity` in java we wrote `Intent(this, Page2.class)`, basically you have to define `Context` in first parameter and destination class in second parameter. According to `Intent` method in source code -

```
 public Intent(Context packageContext, Class<?> cls)
```

As you can see we have to pass `Class<?>` type in second parameter.

By writing `Intent(this, Page2)` we never specify we are going to pass class, we are trying to pass `class` type which is not acceptable.

Use `::class.java` which is alternative of `.class` in kotlin. Use below code to start your `Activity`

```
Intent(this, Page2::class.java)
```

Example -

```
// start your activity by passing the intent
startActivity(Intent(this, Page2::class.java).apply {
    // you can add values(if any) to pass to the next class or avoid using `.apply`
    putExtra("keyIdentifier", value)
})
```

Comment: Any idea why they changed it to `::class.java` instead of `.class` ? The Kotlin approach is unusually complicated, compared to Java.

Comment: @Mr-IDE `class` returns a Kotlin `KClass`, but Android expects a Java `Class<...>`, hence the `.java` property.

Answer (score 59):

Simply you can start an `Activity` in `KOTLIN` by using this simple method,

```
val intent = Intent(this, SecondActivity::class.java)
intent.putExtra("key", value)
startActivity(intent)
```

Comment: You don't need to use putExtra method to start new activity.

Comment: @ShadeToD Yeah! No need to use `putExtra` method. I just added it for passing values when starting new `Activity`

Answer (score 37):

To start a new Activity ,

```
startActivity(Intent(this@CurrentClassName,RequiredClassName::class.java)
```

So change your code to :

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }

    fun buTestUpdateText2 (view: View) {
        startActivity(Intent(this@MainActivity,ClassName::class.java))

        // Also like this 

        val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity,ClassName::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
```

Comment: this@Activity is equal to Java's Activity.this :)

Comment: You forgot to add an ending ')' in startActivity(Intent(this@CurrentClassName,RequiredClassName::class.java)

Comment: Why `this@MainActivity` and not just `this`? I thought `this` always refer to current activity!!

Answer (score 16):

You have to give the second argument of class type. You can also have it a little bit more tidy like below.

```
startActivity(Intent(this, Page2::class.java).apply {
    putExtra("extra_1", value1)
    putExtra("extra_2", value2)
    putExtra("extra_3", value3)
})
```

Answer (score 16):

You can generally simplify the specification of the parameter `BlahActivity::class.java` by defining an inline reified generic function.

```
inline fun <reified T: Activity> Context.createIntent() =
    Intent(this, T::class.java)
```

Because that lets you do

```
startActivity(createIntent<Page2>())
```

Or even simpler

```
inline fun <reified T: Activity> Activity.startActivity() {
    startActivity(createIntent<T>()) 
}
```

So it's now

```
startActivity<Page2>()
```

Comment: As newbie to kotlin, how would you plant a variable number (or none) of putExtra()'s with that?

Comment: You could set up `inline fun <reified T: Activity> Context.createIntent(vararg extras: Pair<String, Any?>) = Intent(this, T::class.java).apply { putExtras(bundleOf(*extras)) }` instead of what I said and it'll work (assuming you have `bundleOf` from android-ktx or anko)

Answer (score 11):

Try this

```
val intent = Intent(this, Page2::class.java)
startActivity(intent)
```

Answer (score 10):

**Well, I found these 2 ways to be the simplest of all outcomes:**

*Way #1:*

```
accoun_btn.setOnClickListener {
            startActivity(Intent(this@MainActivity, SecondActivity::class.java))
        }
```

*Way#2:* (In a generic way)

```
    accoun_btn.setOnClickListener {
        startActivity<SecondActivity>(this)
    }

    private inline fun <reified T> startActivity(context: Context) {
            startActivity(Intent(context, T::class.java))
        }
```

[image: sample]

Answer (score 8):

This is my main activity where i take the username and password from edit text and setting to the intent

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
val userName = null
val password = null
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
button.setOnClickListener {
    val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity,SecondActivity::class.java);
    var userName = username.text.toString()
    var password = password_field.text.toString()
    intent.putExtra("Username", userName)
    intent.putExtra("Password", password)
    startActivity(intent);
 }
}
```

This is my second activity where i have to receive values from the main activity

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
setContentView(R.layout.activity_second)
var strUser: String = intent.getStringExtra("Username")
var strPassword: String = intent.getStringExtra("Password")
user_name.setText("Seelan")
passwor_print.setText("Seelan")
}
```

Answer (score 7):

This is because your `Page2` class doesn't have a companion object which is similar to `static` in Java so to use your class. To pass your class as an argument to `Intent`, you will have to do something like this

```
val changePage = Intent(this, Page2::class.java)
```

Answer (score 5):

**From activity to activity**

```
val intent = Intent(this, YourActivity::class.java)
startActivity(intent)
```

**From fragment to activity**

```
val intent = Intent(activity, YourActivity::class.java)
startActivity(intent)
```

Answer (score 4):

another simple  way of navigating to another activity is

```
Intent(this, CodeActivity::class.java).apply {
                    startActivity(this)
                }
```

Comment: Pls do consider of explaining your code and how it would help, so that others can get benefited from this.

Answer (score 4):

```
fun Context.launchActivity(
    cls: Class<*>,
    flags: Int = 0,
    intentTransformer: Intent.() -> Unit = {}
) {
    val intent = Intent(this, cls).apply {
        addFlags(flags)
        intentTransformer()
    }
    this.startActivity(intent)
}
```

Comment: Code dumps without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your question and explain how it works better than what the OP provided. See [answer].

Comment: For me it worked like a glove, Let me try to explain.
When creating functions like this, you are using advanced and beneficial kotlin techniques, the name of this technique is extension Functions.
I will give an example below:

Answer (score 3):

How about this to consider encapsulation?
For example:

```kotlin
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_contents)

        val title = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_TITLE) ?: EXTRA_TITLE_DEFAULT

        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.frame_layout_fragment, ContentsFragment.newInstance())
            .commit()
    }

    // Omit...

    companion object {

        private const val EXTRA_TITLE = "extra_title"
        private const val EXTRA_TITLE_DEFAULT = "No title"

        fun newIntent(context: Context, title: String): Intent {
            val intent = Intent(context, ContentsActivity::class.java)
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_TITLE, title)
            return intent
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
val intentAct: Intent = Intent(this@YourCurrentActivity, TagentActivity::class.java)
startActivity(intentAct)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, I started to write my application in Kotlin, after I rewrote one of my activities I wanted to see if there are any issues, the problem was that I was not sure how to send an intent from java file to kotlin file.

In this case I created a static function in kotlin (companion object), this function is getting a context (from the current activity) and returning the new intent while using the current context ("java" context) while using the kotlin class ("::class.java").

Here is my code:

```
 //this code will be in the kotlin activity - SearchActivity
 companion object {

    fun newIntent(context: Context): Intent {
        return Intent(context, SearchActivity::class.java)
    }
}

    //this is how you call SearchActivity from MainActivity.java
Intent searchIntent = SearchActivity.Companion.newIntent(this);
startActivity(searchIntent);
```

Comment: If you add `@JvmStatic` to your `newIntent` method you can call it from java without the `Companion` part.

Answer (score 1):

extension Functions

```
fun Activity.showToast(message: String, toastLength: Int){
    //LENGTH_SHORT = 0;
    //LENGTH_LONG = 1;
    Toast.makeText(this, message, toastLength).show()
}

fun Fragment.showToast(message: String, toastLength: Int){
    //LENGTH_SHORT = 0;
    //LENGTH_LONG = 1;
    Toast.makeText(requireContext(), message, toastLength).show()
}

fun Context.launchActivity(
    cls: Class<*>,
    flags: Int = 0,
    intentTransformer: Intent.() -> Unit = {}
) {
    val intent = Intent(this, cls).apply {
        addFlags(flags)
        intentTransformer()
    }
    this.startActivity(intent)
}
```

in an activity call

```
showToast("message to be shown", 1)
```

in a fragment call

```
showToast("message to be shown", 1)
```

start activity from any place

```
 launchActivity(MainActivity::class.java, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
```

[Kotlin Extension function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/idioms.html#extension-functions)

Answer (score 0):

### Details

- Android Studio 3.1.4
- Kotlin version: 1.2.60

### Step 1. Application()

> Get link to the context of you application

```
class MY_APPLICATION_NAME: Application() {

    companion object {
        private lateinit var instance: MY_APPLICATION_NAME
        fun getAppContext(): Context = instance.applicationContext
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        instance = this
        super.onCreate()
    }

}
```

### Step 2. Add Router object

```
object Router {
    inline fun <reified T: Activity> start() {
         val context =  MY_APPLICATION_NAME.getAppContext()
         val intent = Intent(context, T::class.java)
         context.startActivity(intent)
    }
}
```

### Usage

```
// You can start activity from any class: form Application, from any activity, from any fragment and other  
Router.start<ANY_ACTIVITY_CLASS>()
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember to add the activity you want to present, to your `AndroidManifest.xml` too :-) That was the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use both Kotlin and Java files in your application.

To switch between the two files, make sure you give them unique < action android:name="" in AndroidManifest.xml, like so:

```
            <activity android:name=".MainActivityKotlin">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="com.genechuang.basicfirebaseproject.KotlinActivity"/>
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <activity
                android:name="com.genechuang.basicfirebaseproject.MainActivityJava"
                android:label="MainActivityJava" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="com.genechuang.basicfirebaseproject.JavaActivity" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
```

Then in your MainActivity.kt (Kotlin file), to start an Activity written in Java, do this:

```
       val intent = Intent("com.genechuang.basicfirebaseproject.JavaActivity")
        startActivity(intent)
```

In your MainActivityJava.java (Java file), to start an Activity written in Kotlin, do this:

```
       Intent mIntent = new Intent("com.genechuang.basicfirebaseproject.KotlinActivity");
        startActivity(mIntent);
```