# Starting a intent programmatically in Kotlin

Tags: android, android-intent, kotlin

I'm trying to send a user to an activity based off of if their email is verified and then if they have a username.  My code looks like this so far:

```
if (isEmailVerified == true) {                                                    
    if (user.displayName == null) {                                                        
        startIntent(NewUserLayoutProfile)
        } else {
         startIntent(MainActivity)
    }
}
if (isEmailVerified == false) {                                                    
startIntent(ResendEmailVerification)
}
```

And

```
private fun startIntent (theIntent: Activity) {

            val i = Intent(this, theIntent::class.java)
            startActivity(i)
    }
```

How do I pass across the activity?  I tried passing it as a String and that didn't work.  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: you have to pass the `::class.java` like `MainActivity::class.java` to the function, the parameter can be `theIntent: Class<*>`

Comment: Please add this as an answer so I can credit you for the answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kotlin Android start new activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45518139/kotlin-android-start-new-activity)

Comment: No, that question is sending the intent to a method.  Plus it is adding a `.putExtra` to the intent.  Not at all the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the proper code tha works in Kotlin:

```
if (userInfo?.isEmailVerified == false) {
                                        startIntent(ResendEmailVerification::class.java)
                                    } else {
                                        if (userInfo?.displayName != null) {
                                            startIntent(MainActivity::class.java)
                                        } else {
                                            startIntent(NewUserLayoutProfile::class.java)
                                        }
                                    }
```

And

```
private fun startIntent (theIntent: Class<*>) {

            val i = Intent(this, theIntent)
            startActivity(i)
    }
```