# How do I move from one Java Activity to another Kotlin Activity in same project?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I am writing an android app that has both, Java and Kotlin activities. I wished to Move from Kotlin to Java, that is done, now I wish to move back to Kotlin activity, I can't find specific code for that.

My app name is starter and the Kotlin activity is MainActivity.kt and the java class is face_detect.java.
I have already tried:
`

```
btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
```

`

I am expecting to click the button on face_detect.java and that would take me to MainActivity.kt

Answer (score 3):

`this` inside an anonymous class represents that class. Here you need the reference of the Activity in which the button is added.

Change to

```
Intent i = new Intent(MyCurrentActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
```

and replace *MyCurrentActivity* with your current activity name.

Answer (score 0):

Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), KotlinActivity.class);

startActivity(intent);

Replace the KotlinActivity.class with your activity name.

Comment: you can also finish your current activity

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace `Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);` by `Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java);`

Comment: `MainActivity::class.java` starts an activity from a Kotlin class, not java class.

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate of 
[Kotlin Android start new activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45518139/kotlin-android-start-new-activity)

Also inside click listener  instead of passing  "this" ,pass my current activity.this

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code. write normal intent .

```
Intent intent=new Intent(CurrentActivtiy.this,otherActivity.class);
startActivity(inent)
```