# Kotlin Class Reflection Not Working in .kt File

Tags: android, kotlin, reflection

I have a .kt Fragment file in my project and I'm trying to start a new activity with the following code:

```
profilePref?.setOnPreferenceClickListener {
            val profileIntent = Intent(activity, ProfileActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(profileIntent)
            true
        }
```

I have included both

```
implementation ("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.7.10")
```

in my module build.gradle and

```
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions:$kotlin_version"
```

in my project build.gradle, but the class.java still gives me unresolved reference and I'm not really sure why, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Refer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45518762/6784846

Comment: Thanks for the reply but that doesn't answer anything, if you read the question you'll see that I have done exactly as the other post said, but am getting an unresolved reference error on .java.