# Intent in android studio

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent

`var intent = Intent(this@MainActivity,SecondActivity::class.java)`

I'm getting an error in class.java. Idk what's the problem

Comment: please provide error message or more code about your problem

Comment: this is the code that I've used :-                                                                        var intent  = Intent(this@MainActivity,SecondActivity::class.java)

Comment: Okay so I'm learning to link two activities in android studio. So, I've to use intent for this. When I write the above mentioned code android studio is showing an error saying that class.java is an unresolved reference. Idk if I have to import any files for it as Intent class is automatically imported by android .

Answer (score 2):

> You haven't run it try adding code like this for Kotlin

```
val intent  = Intent(this, SecondActivity::class.java)
startActivity(intent)
```

> You haven't run it try adding code like this for java

```
Intent intent= new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: I tried your code and still got the same error. So, I searched for a solution and found one.  The issue is most likely that I forgot to depend on the reflection libraries which were needed for the reflective functions of Kotlin.                             link:- https://stackoverflow.com/a/34159517/20157410